# How to Call a method only once in spite of loading page multiple time?

Tags: java

I have a requirement as follows -

I want to update the some values in DB table on page load
i.e

```
public void parent(){

child()

}

public void child(){
// DB operation
}
```

Every time page loads, it calls the parent() method and so it will call child() method everytime.
But i want to call child() method on first time page load only.

Any idea how to implement in java.

Comment: That depends on the tech stack you are using. Are you using JSP, JSF or a SPA JS app?

Answer (score 1):

In the same class create a boolean field that will remember if the page was loaded:

```
private boolean loaded = false;

public void parent(){
if (!this.loaded)
   child()
}

public void child(){
   this.loaded = true;
   // DB operation
}
```